# How to acces OPC Server data via Utgard directly (without changed(Item item, ItemState state)))?

Tags: java, opc

**Context:**

I found a method to access to the data every time it changes ([Here](https://openscada.atlassian.net/wiki/display/OP/HowToStartWithUtgard)):

```
AccessBase access = new SyncAccess(server, 500) ;   
access.addItem(itemX, new DataCallback() {
    @Override
    public void changed(Item item, ItemState state) {
        updateValueX();
    }
});
```

In my system, I do this with five different values, from item0 to item4, every time it changes, I update the value and it is giving problems.

**Question:**

I need to change this to "Every time the first value changes, get all the values and save them", example:

```
AccessBase access = new SyncAccess(server, 500) ;   
access.addItem(item0, new DataCallback() {
    @Override
    public void changed(Item item, ItemState state) {
        updateValue0();
        updateValue1();
        updateValue2();
        updateValue3();
        updateValue4();
    }
});
```

To do this, I need to call the changed function of the first item/value, but I need to have direct access to the other 4, is there any way I can get these values apart from using the `changed(Item item, ItemState state)` function?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it:

**Constructor:**

```
//ON THE CONSTRUCTOR, INITIALIZE GROUP AND ITEMS
org.openscada.opc.lib.da.Group group = server.addGroup("GroupName");
Item items[] = new Item[numberOfItems]= group.addItem("itemID"); 
//YOU WILL NEED TO HAVE ACCESS TO items[] LATER, MAKE IT PUBLIC.

for (int index = 0; index < numberOfItems; index++) {
    items[index] = group.addItem("item"+index);
}
```

**changed() function of the main item you access (item0):**

```
access.addItem(item0, new DataCallback() {
    @Override
    public void changed(Item item0, ItemState state) {

        //where items[] is the item created using group.addItem("item"+index) in the constructor
        JIArray jiArray = items[1].read(true).getValue().getObjectAsArray(); 
        Object[] arrayObj = (Object[]) jiArray.getArrayInstance();

        // arrayObj contains the value (or values) of the item 

        for (Object v : arrayObj) {

        }
    }
});
```

This is a method I figured out myself. Taking into account that I have pretty much no experience with OPC and Utgard, I assume this is not the best method (performance wise) to access the data, it just works.

I will update if I ever find out how to optimize or improve the access.